# Class not initializing properly for MYSQL database in C++

Tags: c++, mysql, class

I am trying to create a class to hold a connection to the database so I can use normal functions to make queries to the database. However, for instance, if I try do that in main I get an ERROR:

```
\main.cpp|280|error: cannot convert 'int (attribute((stdcall)) )(SOCKET, const sockaddr, int) {aka int (attribute((stdcall)) )(unsigned int, const sockaddr, int)}' to 'MYSQL* {aka st_mysql}' for argument '1' to 'int mysql_query(MYSQL, const char*)'|
```

Here is my code below:

```
class Connection {
    public:
        int init() {
        MYSQL *connect; // Create a pointer to the MySQL instance
        connect=mysql_init(NULL); // Initialise the instance
        /* This If is irrelevant and you don't need to show it. I kept it in for Fault Testing.*/
        if(!connect)    /* If instance didn't initialize say so and exit with fault.*/
        {
            cout << "MySQL Initialization Failed";
            return 1;
        }
        /* Now we will actually connect to the specific database.*/
        connect=mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);
        /* Following if statements are unneeded too, but it's worth it to show on your
        first app, so that if your database is empty or the query didn't return anything it
        will at least let you know that the connection to the mysql server was established. */
            cout << "[+] Exchange Order Book v1.0\n";
            cout << "[+] Attempting connection to database\n";
        if(connect){
            cout << "[+] Connection Success!\n";
            cout << "[+] Loading initializationn\n";
        }
        else{
            cout << "[!] Connection Failed!\n";
            return 0;
        }
        MYSQL_RES *res_set; /* Create a pointer to recieve the return value.*/
        MYSQL_ROW row;  /* Assign variable for rows. */
       // mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM orderque");
        /* Send a query to the database. */
        unsigned int i = 1; /* Create a counter for the rows */

        }
    };
```

Main():

```
  Connection.init();
  mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM orderque");
```

Weird thing is if I have the class data just in main it works 100% fine, just when I try to make it global or put it in a class it gives me errors

Comment: What is `connect` ? Could it be the name of a function?

Comment: Why do you tag C, if you are trying to work with classes?

Comment: I tagged C because it is a C MYSQL wrapper, connect is a instance of MYSQL

Comment: @Rand -- The code you wrote is C++, it is not C.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie good point, i deleted the tag

Comment: What happens if you rename `connect` to `connectionNamedArthur` inside `main()` ?

Comment: It looks like you're not defining `connect` in `main()`, so it's trying to call `mysql_query()` with the [connect](https://linux.die.net/man/3/connect) function as the first argument. If you rename it to `connectionNamedArthur` as suggested by Yunnosch, you'll likely get an error telling you it's not defined. You should rather call it something like `conn` and convert your Connection class into a function that returns `conn`. Then in main, assign that to a local var to use in the mysql_query() call. Otherwise store the conn in a field in Connection, instantiate it and ref it in mysql_query()